# React Native - Change Stylesheet Dynamically

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Im coding a project in react native which requires rtl support (english and arabic). I however am experimenting with my own code rather then using a rtl plugin. Straight to the point i want to know is it possible that i can dynamically change stylesheet , so that all classes where : position:absolute. If it has a property left or right, to inverse it?

Fo example if a class is positioned absolutely, and has the : 
Left:20,

Can i automagically make this become :
Right:20,

And same for the other way around? Is this possible in react native.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do something like

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  yourView: {
    left: isRight ? 0 : 20,
    right: isRight? 20: 0,
  },
});
```

Where isRight is a variable you've defined previously

Another approach would be to create to separate it into different styles and attach the styles on render. Something like

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  yourView: {
    ...common styles here
  },
  leftView: {
    left: 20,
  },
  rightView: {
    right: 0,
  },
});
```

Then in the render method u would attach the styles as:

```
render() {
  return (
    <View styles={[styles.mainView, isRight ? styles.leftView : styles.rightView]}/>
  )
}
```